# Execute same command multiple times, changing only the value of a single variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, sh

New to scripting, I need the script to replace $takevaluefrombelow$ from the channel list and run the download command until there are no channel left, how do i archive that?  Thanks

```
/home/server/yt-dlp  --match-filter "title~=(?i)앨리스" --write-thumbnail --write-subs --sub-langs all --write-description --write-annotations --write-info-json --continue --ignore-errors --convert-thumbnails jpg  --download-archive done.txt "https://www.youtube.com/$value$/search?query=앨리스"

@channel1

@channel2

@channel5

@channel7

@ewchannel7
```

I need the script to replace $takevaluefrombelow$ from the channel list and run the download command until there are no channel left, how do i archive that?

Comment: You can store your channel names in an array and iterate over the values using a for loop. Also, `$value$` is not valid bash syntax. You probably mean `$value`

Comment: @Aserre : Do be precise: `$value$` **is** valid. Provided that no variable name follows after the second `$`, it is just a parameter expansion of `value`, followed by a literal $. It's weird, but not illegal.

Comment: I don't see any occurance of _takevaluefrombelow_  in the code you posted.